# preallocate list in R

Tags: performance, r, list, memory

It is inefficient in R to expand a data structure in a loop.  How do I preallocate a `list` of a certain size? `matrix` makes this easy via the `ncol` and `nrow` arguments.  How does one do this in lists?  For example:

```
x <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
    x[[i]] <- i
}
```

I presume this is inefficient.  What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`vector` can create empty vector of the desired mode and length.

```
x <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
```

Comment: I find myself back at this answer approximately every 2-3 months

Answer (score 25):

To expand on what @Jilber said, `lapply` is specially built for this type of operation.

instead of the for loop, you could use:

```
x <- lapply(1:10, function(i) i)
```

You can extend this to more complicated examples.  Often, what is in the body of the for loop can be directly translated to a function which accepts a single row that looks like a row from each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You could also just do `x <- lapply(1:10, c)` to avoid the anonymous function. It's 2.5 microseconds faster on my machine.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
   x <- vector('list', 10)
```

But using lapply is the best choice

Answer (score 1):

All 3 existing answers are great.

The reason the `vector()` function can create a *list* is explained in [JennyBC's purrr tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/bk00_vectors-and-lists.html):

> **A list is actually still a vector in R, but it’s not an atomic vector.** We construct a list explicitly with list() but, like atomic vectors, most lists are created some other way in real life.

#### To preallocate a list

```r
list <- vector(mode = "list", length = 10)
```

#### To preallocate a [vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414062/5783745)

```r
vec <- rep(NA, 10)
```