# NSLOOKUP in R (rstats)

Tags: r, nslookup

I am new to scripting and R.

In the Windows cmd.exe I can perform an NSLOOKUP on a domain by:

> nslookup www.google.com

I have a dataset of domain names that I would like to verify as valid or invalid as part of my grouping process in R.  Is there a way to do NSLOOKUP in base R or one of the packages?

Edit1:
I made some alterations to loop through 3 domains using the system call suggested.  The call works, however the output will not save directly into a vector (line 7 below).  How would I need to rework this line so that I can capture the output?

```
domains <- c('www.google.com','www.badtestdomainnotvalid.com','www.yahoo.com')
dns <- vector()
dnsreturn <-vector()
for(i in 1:length(domains)){
  dns[i] <- paste('nslookup ',domains[i],sep='')
  dnsreturn[i] <- system(dns[i],intern=TRUE)}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nothing else you could do

```
system("nslookup www.google.com", intern=TRUE)
```

In response to your edit:

```
domains = c('www.google.com','www.badtestdomainnotvalid.com','www.yahoo.com')
sapply(domains, function(x) system(paste("nslookup", x), intern=TRUE))
```

This will return a list of vectors, you can manipulate as you see fit beyond that

Comment: THat worked for a single line, I'm editing my question to include altering your solution to save the output from making the system call back into a vector or frame.

Comment: @ConnieMarie Note that Geoff didn't initialize his objects like you're doing in the question.  [It's a good idea to preallocate a vector if it's going to get really big](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464379/preallocate-list-in-r), but you need to specify the length or it doesn't do you any good.  It's an even better idea to use the `apply` family of functions like Geoff does above.