# Too large output in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am writing a for loop program in RStudio.

When I use the following command,

```
a <- 10
for (i in c(1:10335) { 
    a <- a + 0.005
    print(a)
}
```

I get a very large output in console, since the loop runs 10335 times. That large output is also a small fraction of the total output (a few, maybe 1000 or so, values from the last). I also loose my written program in the console. How do I fix this issue? How can I get a complete set of 10335 values in the output?

Also, is there any way to export this output in excel or in text format?

Comment: what you want to have for output, your output is natural for the loop you have

Comment: Are you not typing your code into the source file pane and executing it from there?

Comment: What is your intention? Try `a <- 10`,  `out <- 10 + c(0:9)*0.005` and have a look at `out`. Perhaps you also should have a look at `seq`

Comment: You can save output to a file. You can store output in a vector (or matrix or dataframe) which can be exported (say as a csv file) which is then imported to Excel. If you store the output to a vector you can use the `View` function to inspect it. As you have discovered, having thousands of print statements is seldom helpful.

Comment: @nrussell No, I was trying to do it in console. Even with the source file pane, I am getting the same issue in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can avoid for loop using `seq()`:

```
# using seq instead of forloop
res <- seq(from = 10 + 0.005, to = 10 + 10335 * 0.005, by = 0.005)
# and write to a file
write.table(res, "temp_seq.txt", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Or if we must use loop then use `sink()` function:

```
# using loop and sink the output to a file
sink("temp_loop.txt")
a <- 10
for (i in c(1:10335)) { 
  a <- a + 0.005
  print(a)
}
sink()
```

In both cases we are writing output to a file, as RStudio console has a limits on print.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of printing the values, you can add them to an existing vector:

```
a <- 10
results <- vector(length = 10335)
for (i in c(1:10335)) {
a <- a + 0.005
results[i] <- a
}

str(results)
num [1:10335] 10 10 10 10 10 ...
```

You can save the result to a text file using write.table:

```
write.table(results, file = "results.txt", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Don't do it this way -- preallocate space for the vector. You have just turned what should be a linear algorithm into a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: Isn't the whole vector copied on modification whether the length is preallocated or not?

Comment: No, it isn't. R would be a dreadfully slow language if things worked that way. See the accepted answer to : http://stackoverflow.com/q/12464379/4996248 about how to use `vector` to preallocate. Your answer is otherwise quite good. I'll upvote it if you tweak it (the downvote wasn't by me. by the way).