# Efficient way of binding rows of data.frame to another data.frame in a loop?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am aware that the most memory-efficient way of appending to a vector or list in a loop is to [preallocate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464430/5783745) that vector/list, before assigning to its indices.

#### Question:

What is the most memory (and time) efficient way of rbinding ***data.frames*** to oneanother in a loop? (Note: ultimately, I am after the most efficient, sensible way of binding large numbers of large data.frames in a loop)

#### What I know so far:

We could use the standard `rbind`, example:

```
output <- data.frame(a=c(), b=c())

for(i in 1:1000) { 
  temp <- data.frame(a=c(i), b=c(i))
  output <- rbind(output, temp)
}
```

Or `bind_rows()`: (which [should be faster](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html))

```
library(dplyr)
output <- data.frame(a=c(), b=c())

for(i in 1:1000) { 
  temp <- data.frame(a=c(i), b=c(i))
  output <- bind_rows(output, temp)
}
```

I am not sure if one of these is significantly more efficient (e.g. for long/large operations), nor if there are other, more efficient alternatives / best-practices?

Comment: Neither are good for large operations.  Don't bind inside a loop - it creates unnecessary copies of the data quickly becomes a real bottleneck. Return the data in a list and bind once.

Comment: @H1 I guess sensible steps are: i) [preallocate list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464379/preallocate-list-in-r/12464430#12464430), then ii) assign data.frames to list indices, iii) bind everything at the end with `bind_rows(output_list)`?

Answer (score 4):

As OP suggested in comments, the best thing to do is to make a large list and then bind everything at the end. This uses `lapply()` instead of an explicit loop followed by `do.call(rbind, tmp)`:

```
n = 1000
tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) data.frame(a = i, b = i))
output = do.call(rbind, tmp)
## or 
output = dplyr::bind_rows(tmp)
## or
output = data.table::rbindlist(tmp)
```

Now if we target this particular example while requiring a loop, we can also use a couple of alternatives. For instance, instead of growing a list of dataframes, we know each iteration will result in an integer. Therefore, we could simply pre-allocate integer vectors which is also easy to translate to [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp):

```
n = 1000L
a = b = integer(n)
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
  a[i] = b[i] = i
}
data.frame(a = a, b = b)

## or with Rcpp:
rcpp_new_loop = Rcpp::cppFunction(code = 
'DataFrame rcpp_new_loop(int n) {
   IntegerVector a(n);
   IntegerVector b(n);

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     a(i) = b(i) = i + 1;
   }
   return(DataFrame::create(Named("a") = a, _["b"] = b));
 } 
')
```

Similarly, there is a lot of overhead for `data.frame` calls. `dplyr::bind_rows()` and `data.table::rbindlist()` default to `data.frame` type of results for `lists`:

```
tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) list(a = i, b = i))

##data.table
output = rbindlist(tmp)
setDF(output)

##dplyr
output = bind_rows(tmp)
as.data.frame(output)
```

Performance:
Rcpp is unsurprisingly the fastest approach. But using `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows` with a list is a pretty simple approach.

```
### n = 1,000 
# A tibble: 9 x 13
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 OP               378.18ms 379.92ms      2.63    15.7MB     2.63     2     2      760ms
2 do_call          254.76ms 254.89ms      3.92   220.7KB     5.88     2     3      510ms
3 bind_rows_df     196.69ms 202.48ms      4.94    16.9KB     3.29     3     2      607ms
4 dt_df            179.41ms 184.76ms      4.52    32.8KB     3.01     3     2      664ms
5 bind_rows_list     2.74ms   2.81ms    321.      16.9KB     3.98   161     2      502ms
6 new_loop           2.56ms   2.63ms    342.      17.6KB     4.00   171     2      500ms
7 dt_list            1.33ms   1.35ms    525.      32.8KB     3.99   263     2      501ms
8 new_loop_fx(n)    270.2us  280.5us   2188.      11.8KB     4.00  1094     2      500ms
9 rcpp_new_loop(n)  217.4us  228.3us   3872.      10.4KB     4.00  1936     2      500ms

### n = 10,000
# A tibble: 9 x 13
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 OP                  5.69s    5.69s     0.176    1.51GB     5.80     1    33      5.69s
2 do_call             2.67s    2.67s     0.374     2.2MB     3.74     1    10      2.67s
3 bind_rows_df        1.92s    1.92s     0.520  157.52KB     4.16     1     8      1.92s
4 dt_df               2.25s    2.25s     0.444  243.77KB     4.44     1    10      2.25s
5 bind_rows_list    30.73ms  34.57ms    28.5    157.75KB     3.81    15     2   525.49ms
6 new_loop           3.64ms   3.79ms   238.     123.07KB     3.99   119     2   500.85ms
7 dt_list           14.68ms  17.98ms    49.8    243.77KB     5.98    25     3      502ms
8 new_loop_fx(n)      1.2ms   1.24ms   691.     117.28KB     7.99   346     4   500.55ms
9 rcpp_new_loop(n)  299.5us  313.3us  2818.      80.66KB     4.00  1409     2   499.96ms

##code to reproduce::
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

n = 1000L

new_loop_fx = function(n){
  a = b = integer(n)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    a[i] = b[i] = i
  }
  data.frame(a = a, b = b)
}

rcpp_new_loop = Rcpp::cppFunction(code = 
'DataFrame rcpp_new_loop(int n) {
   IntegerVector a(n);
   IntegerVector b(n);

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     a(i) = b(i) = i + 1;
   }
   return(DataFrame::create(Named("a") = a, _["b"] = b));
 } 
')

bench::mark(
  OP = {
    output <- data.frame(a=c(), b=c())

    for(i in seq_len(n)) { 
      temp <- data.frame(a=i, b=i)
      output <- rbind(output, temp)
    }
    output
  }
  ,
  do_call = {
    tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) data.frame(a = i, b = i))
    output = do.call(rbind, tmp)
  }
  , 
  bind_rows_df = {
    tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) data.frame(a = i, b = i))
    output = bind_rows(tmp)
    as.data.frame(output)
  }
  ,
  dt_df = {
    tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) data.frame(a = i, b = i))
    output = rbindlist(tmp)
    setDF(output)
  }
  , 
  bind_rows_list = {
    tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) list(a = i, b = i))
    output = bind_rows(tmp)
    as.data.frame(output)
  }
  ,
  new_loop = {
    a = b = integer(n)
    for (i in seq_len(n)){
      a[i] = b[i] = i
    }
    data.frame(a = a, b = b)
  }
  ,
  dt_list = {
    tmp = lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) list(a = i, b = i))
    output = rbindlist(tmp)
    setDF(output)
  }

  ,
  new_loop_fx(n),
  rcpp_new_loop(n)
)
```

Comment: how abt adding a data.table soln? :)

Comment: @chinsoon12 thanks for reminding me. My brief findings are that ```bind_rows``` and ```rbindlist``` are largely equivalent - there's a lot of garbage collection that starts to affect the timings.