# Repercussions of a NULL classed object from `obj <- {}` in R?

Tags: r

The syntax `obj <- {}` caught my eye in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3417894/168689.  I'm fairly new to `R` and hadn't seen it before so I fired up my console:

```
obj <- {}
class(obj)
```

and found an object of class `NULL`.

```
class(obj) 
[1] "NULL"
```

I'd like to know the opinions on this technique in the R community.  Is there merit in it? Do the possible downsides (really, no class?) outweigh those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` is equivalent to `NULL`. Note `identical({}, NULL)` is `TRUE`. `NULL` is clearer, imo, but there are no repercussions to using `{}` instead---except maybe the risk of inducing momentary confusion on someone reviewing your code.