# adding values to the vector inside for loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have just started learning R and I wrote this code to learn on functions and loops.

```
squared<-function(x){
  m<-c()
  for(i in 1:x){
    y<-i*i
    c(m,y)
  }
  return (m)
}
squared(5)  

NULL
```

Why does this return NULL. I want `i*i` values to append to the end of `m`and return a vector. Can someone please point out whats wrong with this code.

Comment: You never put anything inside `m <- c()`.

Comment: I guess you want `m <- c(m, y)` instead of just `c(m, y)`. That being said, you really shouldn't build vectors by appending one element at a time -- see the second circle of [the R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for details. Part of the beauty of R is its vectorized operations -- you can just do `squared <- function(x) x^2`. This is both much less typing and much more efficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You haven't put anything inside `m <- c()` in your loop since you did not use an assignment. You are getting the following -

```
m <- c()
m
# NULL
```

You can change the function to return the desired values by assigning `m` in the loop.

```
squared <- function(x) {
    m <- c()
    for(i in 1:x) {
        y <- i * i
        m <- c(m, y)
    }
    return(m)
}

squared(5)
# [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

But this is inefficient because we know the length of the resulting vector will be 5 (or `x`).  So we want to allocate the memory first before looping.  This will be the better way to use the `for()` loop.

```
squared <- function(x) {
    m <- vector("integer", x)
    for(i in seq_len(x)) {
        m[i] <- i * i
    }
    m
}

squared(5)
# [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

Also notice that I have removed `return()` from the second function. It is not necessary there, so it can be removed.  It's a matter of personal preference to leave it in this situation.  Sometimes it will be necessary, like in `if()` statements for example.

I know the question is about looping, but I also must mention that this can be done more efficiently with seven characters using the primitive `^`, like this

```
(1:5)^2
# [1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

`^` is a primitive function, which means the code is written entirely in C and will be the most efficient of these three methods

```
`^`
# function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("^")
```

Comment: 7 characters... pfft. Wasteful!

Comment: @thelatemail - I feel like I might have over-done it there.  Haha

Comment: @RichardScriven Thank You for the explanation. I would like to know why `<-` are used and can't `=` be used in R? That is can't I code as `y=i*i`? Is it necessary to be as `y<-i*i`

Comment: @sam_rox either works here. You can read more about the differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general approach:

```
# Create empty vector
vec <- c()

for(i in 1:10){

  # Inside the loop, make one or elements to add to vector
  new_elements <- i * 3
  
  # Use 'c' to combine the existing vector with the new_elements
  vec <- c(vec, new_elements)

}

vec
#  [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
```

---

- If you happen to run out of memory (e.g. if your loop has a lot of iterations or vectors are large), you can try [vector preallocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3414062/5783745) which will be more efficient. That's not usually necessary unless your vectors are particularly large though.