# Adding random numbers to the end of a vector

Tags: r, function, for-loop, random

I am trying to repeatedly compute the median of a random vector, constructing a vector of all the medians. Why do I get a `NULL` result from my code below, in which I repeatedly compute the median and add it to the end of the vector `m`?

```
medainfunc<-function(n,mu,sigma,iterate){
  m<-c()
  for (i in itreate){
    x<-rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
    y<-median(x)
    m<-c(m,y)
  }
  m
}
medianfunc(10,3,15,10000)
NULL
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366694/adding-values-to-the-vector-inside-for-loop-in-r).  Also  try with `for(i in seq(iterate))`  Check the typo in `iterate` and `itreate` and `medainfunc` and `medianfunc` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have multiple typos in the OP's code, i.e. `iterate` vs. `itreate` and calling `medainfunc` while the original function is `medianfunc`.  In addition, we are providing only a single input value for 'iterate', so `seq(iterate` may be we want inside the function.  Otherwise, we get a single value output.

```
medianfunc<-function(n,mu,sigma,iterate){
  m<-c()
  for (i in seq(iterate)){
    x<-rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
    y<-median(x)
    m<-c(m,y)
  }
  m
}

set.seed(25)
medianfunc(10,3,15, 5)
#[1]  0.9770646 -6.4852741  4.6768291 -6.4167869  5.3176253
```

This could be vectorized by getting the `rnorm` of 'n*iterate' values.  Convert this to a `matrix` and use `colMedians` from `library(matrixStats)`.

```
medianfunc1 <- function(n, mu, sigma, iterate){
  m1 <- matrix(rnorm(n*iterate, mu, sigma), ncol=iterate)
  library(matrixStats)
  colMedians(m1)
}

set.seed(25)
medianfunc1(10,3,15, 5)
#[1]  0.9770646 -6.4852741  4.6768291 -6.4167869  5.3176253
```

Comment: should he also add `return` to the customized function?

Comment: @DiegoAgher  Wrapping `return` around 'm' is not needed.  For clarity, it can be used.

Comment: @akrun I corrected those typos. But still I get `null` even when I used `seq(iterate)`

Comment: @clarkson Using the function in my solution returns the values as I showed.  You can check whether you are still having some typos.

Comment: @akrun The problem was wrote as `m}`  in single line. Why can't I do it?

Comment: @clarkson  Sorry, didn't get your comment.  If you are writing in a single line, then use `;` to separate each if I understand your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Building a vector one-by-one is both inefficient (see the second circle of [the R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)) and code-intensive. Instead, you can repeat a randomized operation a certain number of times in a single line of code with the `replicate` function:

```
medianfunc <- function(n, mu, sigma, iterate) {
  replicate(iterate, median(rnorm(n, mu, sigma)))
}
set.seed(25)
medianfunc(10,3,15, 5)
# [1]  0.9770646 -6.4852741  4.6768291 -6.4167869  5.3176253
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is just the code you wrote on the post but the function is called `medainfunc` and then on your code you are calling the `medianfunc`. That might be just one error, the other thing I noticed is that you should add `return`
at the end of your function like so:

```
medainfunc<-function(n,mu,sigma,iterate){
   m<-c()
   for (i in itreate){
     x<-rnorm(n,mu,sigma)
     y<-median(x)
     m<-c(m,y)
     }
   return(m)
   }
```

Comment: Still a typo, as highlighted by akrun.