Question on Returning a user-defined function (learning R from scratch)
I'm learning R programming from scratch on my own since September and I'm taking a free beginner course from Educative. In the session about creating a function and returning the output for other task, I came across an exercise that I really don't understand the solution. I'm wondering if anyone could explain this to someone who doesn't have a programming background?
Problem Statement
Implement a function "evenOdd" that takes a "vector" of numbers as input and returns a "vector" where each element of the output "vector" has the string “even” or “odd” depending on the corresponding element of the input vector.
Input
A "testVariable" containing the "vector" to be tested.
Output
A "vector" where each element is either “even” or “odd” depending on the state of the corresponding element of the input "testVariable" vector.
Sample Input
testVariable <- c(78, 100, 2)
Sample Output
"even" "even" "even"
The solution they gave:(I also attached it as an image)
evenOdd <- function(testVariable) 
{
  output <- vector("character", 0) # initializing an empty character vector

  for(v in testVariable)
  {
    if(v %% 2 == 0)
    {
      # Insert even in vector if conditional statement satisfied
      output <- c(output, "even") 
    }
    else
    {
      # Insert odd in vector if conditional statement not satisfied
      output <- c(output, "odd")
    }
  }
  return(output) # returning the output vector. 
  # You can also simply write output here.
}

# Driver Code
evenOdd(c(78, 100, 2))

I understand the for loop and the if...else statements, but what I don't understand is the codes "output <- vector("character", 0)" on line 3, why you have to define that? I'm not sure what does "initializing an empty character vector" mean, they never covered that in the course.
Secondly, why they have to define output again with the code " output <- c(output, "even")" in line 10 and 15?
Also, I suppose a vector can only contain values of the same type? Why is there a String and an Integer in the same vector (as in line 3)? I would really appreciate it if someone can elaborate and explain the solution.
Thank you!
I tried to not include the output but it doesn't work.

If this is the expected answer they gave, the course isn’t very good. :-( — You can write code like this, but it’s not how you would normally write it, and it should definitely not be taught before the idiomatic way.

It's bad form to iteratively grow an object in R. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366694/adding-values-to-the-vector-inside-for-loop-in-r

A better function: evenOdd <- function(x) c("even", "odd")[x%%2 + 1]

@jblood94 Yes, though that might be a tad too advanced.

Don't take this course. It is teaching bad habits for R.

Was their solution generated by a (badly trained) AI engine? @KonradRudolph is right indeed, as indeed jblood94 and MrFlick.  If jblood94s really was too advanced, then at least MrFlick's one-liner should been shown.

Thank you guys so much for your comments! It's good to know that this course is not good! Do you have any recommendation for which (complete) beginner course to take for R? My goal is to use R to analyze 'omics' data in biomedical science. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated!! Thank you!

The "solution" they provided is not very "R-like".
It would be better to write the function just like
evenOdd <- function(x) ifelse(x%%2==0, "even", "odd")

The issue is that appending an element one at a time is not the most efficient way to do things.
When the run
output <- vector("character", 0)

They are defining a variable named output that points to an empty character vector. (you may also see this sometimes written as output <- c()). But it's literally saying create a vector that will hold "character" values with exactly 0 elements in it (i.e. make it empty). But the point is, you need to initialize the variable so R knows where to store stuff. If you didn't have that line, and then R tried to run the command
output <- c(output, "even") 

it would have no idea what output is so it could not perform c(output, "even") which is appending the value of "event" to the vector output since the vector output does not exist.
Again, most people who use R more regularly would never write code that way. I might not trust the rest of that course.

Thank you @MrFlick for the explanation!! I understand the 'output <- vector("character", 0)' now. But I don't understand the line 'output <- c(output, "even")'
what does that mean?

c() is the concatenate function. It's used to combine vectors. In this case, it takes the contents of output, adds one more value "even" to the end, then saves then overwrites the value of output with the updated value.
