# For loop in R return error 'object not found'

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm learning R and have written my first for-loop. For 1000 iterations I create 4 vectors, each with the dimensions 10, 100, 1000  and 10000 elements. These so called theta1 values are not recognised. I tried running one theta1 at the time and it works but running all 4 gives the error 'object not found'. It's not obvious to me what's wrong here, can anyone explain?

```
k=1000

'Method1'

for(i in 1:k){
  N10=runif(10) 
  N100=runif(100)
  N1000=runif(1000)
  N10000=runif(10000)
  theta1_10[i]=(1/10)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10^2))
  theta1_100[i]=(1/100)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N100^2))
  theta1_1000[i]=(1/1000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N1000^2))
  theta1_10000[i]=(1/10000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10000^2))
}

'Result Method 1'
m_theta1_10 = mean(theta1_10)
sd_theta1_10 = sd(theta1_10)
m_theta1_100 = mean(theta1_100)
sd_theta1_100 = sd(theta1_100)
m_theta1_1000 = mean(theta1_1000)
sd_theta1_1000 = sd(theta1_1000)
m_theta1_10000 = mean(theta1_10000)
sd_theta1_10000 = sd(theta1_10000)
```

Comment: What is `'Method 1`? You are not coding in `vba`. If you want a comment use `#` instead! That's not your problem though.

Comment: You need to initialize `theta1_10` to `theta1_100000` before the for loop. For example `theta1_10 = vector(,k)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an empty R vector to add new items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413879/how-to-create-an-empty-r-vector-to-add-new-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initial a vector before assigning values to it.
For this case it is:

```
# Initialize
k=1000
theta1_10 = vector(,k)
theta1_100 = vector(,k)
theta1_1000 = vector(,k)
theta1_10000 = vector(,k)

# Method1
for(i in 1:k){
  N10=runif(10) 
  N100=runif(100)
  N1000=runif(1000)
  N10000=runif(10000)
  theta1_10[k] = (1/10)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10^2))
  theta1_100[k] = (1/100)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N100^2))
  theta1_1000[k] = (1/1000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N1000^2))
  theta1_10000[k] = (1/10000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10000^2))
}

# Result Method 1
result = data.frame(mean = c(mean(theta1_10),mean(theta1_100),mean(theta1_1000),mean(theta1_10000)),
                    sd = c(sd(theta1_10),sd(theta1_100),sd(theta1_1000),sd(theta1_10000)))
rownames(result) <- c("theta1_10","theta1_100","theta1_1000","theta1_10000")
result

                 mean          sd
theta1_10    3.145259 0.287263626
theta1_100   3.142640 0.089207786
theta1_1000  3.140476 0.027901399
theta1_10000 3.141695 0.009046627
```

Comment: Thanks, assigning a vector made the deal. To understand better, is theta1_10 as parameter in theta1_10 = c(theta1_10, (1/10)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10^2))) appending to the vector theta1_10?

Comment: Yes, `c(theta1_10, ....)` means append the following to that `theta1_10`. And as Uwe Block pointed out, it's not a good idea when k is large.

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this answer because both the question and the accepted answer (before it was edited) demonstrate bad programming style in R: *They are growing a vector in a for loop*. (See *Circle 2* of [Patrick Burns' *The R Inferno*](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).)

The effect will become clear from a simple benchmark. The task is to create a vector `x` which will contain the integer numbers 1 to `k`:

```
k <- 10000L
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  grow = {
    x <- integer(0)
    for (i in seq.int(k)) x <- c(x, i)
    x
  },
  subscript = {
    x <- integer(k)
    for (i in seq.int(k)) x[i] <- i
    x
  },
  colon_operator = {
    x <- 1L:k
    x
  },
  times = 10L
)
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr       min        lq        mean    median        uq        max neval
#           grow 93491.676 96127.568 104219.0140 97123.627 99459.343 165545.063    10
#      subscript  9067.607  9215.996   9483.0962  9551.288  9771.795   9938.307    10
# colon_operator     5.664     7.552      7.9675     8.307     8.685      9.063    10
```

It's evident that even for a small vector of length 10000 appending elements is a magnitude slower than allocating the required length beforehand. The timing of the colon operator is included here to demonstrate the benefit of the built-in vectorized functions.

So both codes in question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43149120/3817004) need to be re-written to use subscripting in order to improve efficiency.

```
# initialize the random number generator for reproducible results
set.seed(1234L)
# allocate memory for the vectors beforehand
theta1_10 = numeric(k)
theta1_100 = numeric(k)
theta1_1000 = numeric(k)
theta1_10000 = numeric(k)

# Method1
for(i in seq.int(k)){
  N10=runif(10) 
  N100=runif(100)
  N1000=runif(1000)
  N10000=runif(10000)
  # update by subscripting
  theta1_10[i] = (1/10)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10^2))
  theta1_100[i] = (1/100)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N100^2))
  theta1_1000[i] = (1/1000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N1000^2))
  theta1_10000[i] = (1/10000)*4*sum(sqrt(1-N10000^2))
}
```

---

However, the whole code can be re-written in a much more concise way:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
k <- 1000L
N <- 10^(1:4)
rbindlist(
  lapply(N, function(i) {
    theta1 <- replicate(k, 4 / i * sum(sqrt(1 - runif(i)^2)))
    data.table(N = i, mean = mean(theta1), sd = sd(theta1))
  }))
#       N     mean         sd
#1:    10 3.144974 0.27238683
#2:   100 3.140716 0.09040696
#3:  1000 3.141791 0.02654225
#4: 10000 3.141585 0.00886737
```